# Create cropped thumbnails with Python from variable image sizes / aspect ratios

Tags: python, image, thumbnails, crop, image-size

After taking screenshots of websites I would like to generate thumbnails from them.

I created some simple code to test and I am getting screenshots. The problem is the size is not fixed when I set to 200x150. I would like to create thumbnails by cropping the image in height (not width!) and thumbnail them to a size of 200x150 (fixed for height/weight).

As an example:

```
size = 200, 150

# create thumbnail from 1024x768 screenshot
im = Image.open('/var/www/public/tester.png')
im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save('/var/www/public/testtumnb.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Outputs:

[image: outputs]  
[image: outputs]

I would like to create thumbnails like the second image.

Answer (score 1):

The PIL resize method resizes the image and retains its original aspect ratio so that if your input image is 1000x2000, when it is resized to your size (200x150) you will get 200x400 and not 200x150 (you can check it by using im.size before save). If you want only top part from thumbnail image you have to use im.crop after im.thumbnail (see http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)